# Como eu faço prevenir que o input do usuário não resulte em um ValueError, e pedir para o programa refazer a pergunta

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso aprender como verificar se o input vai resultar em um ValueError, e em seguida re-executar o pedido de input até o valor ser um número inteiro.

Meu problema:

```
QuantidadeCabos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: "))
```

Se o usuário digitar um string por exemplo logo em seguida já recebo esta mensagem de erro

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'teste'
```

Queria prevenir este erro e avisar o usuário por exemplo
"Digite um número inteiro!"

e logo em seguida já re-executar o pedido do input.

---

Edit:

Funcionou, mas, quando eu chamo a variável diz que ela não foi definida,desculpa pela burrice como resolvo esse problema?

NameError: name 'QuantidadeCabos' is not defined

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
def perguntacabos():
QuantidadeCabos = input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: ")
try:
    return int(QuantidadeCabos)
except ValueError as err:
    print("Digite um Número inteiro!")
return perguntacabos()
```

Chamei a função:

```
perguntacabos()
```

E depois fiz um teste para ver se o valor está correto
preciso que seja inserido entre 3 e 6:

(Aqui eu ainda não alterei nada ainda , oque faço para funcionar?)

```
while QuantidadeCabos < 3 or QuantidadeCabos > 6:
    print("Digite um valor entre 3 e 6!")
    QuantidadeCabos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes evitar 're-chamando' `input()`.

A solução para isso (não haver *trigger* da excepção) passa convencionalmente por um bloco `try/catch`:

```
try:
    int(input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: "))
except ValueError as err:
    print('format errado') # value error
```

**solução recursiva:**

```
def return_int():
    QuantidadeCabos = input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: ")
    try: 
        return int(QuantidadeCabos)
    except ValueError as err: # formato errado
        print('Formato errado')
    return return_int() # repetir a pergunta

print("Quantidade de cabos: ", return_int())
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/AliveSilverLanserver)

**solução iterativa:**

```
while True: # enquanto nao houver break
    QuantidadeCabos = input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: ")
    try:
        int(QuantidadeCabos)
        break # tudo bem pode retornar
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Formato errado')
print("Quantidade de cabos: ", QuantidadeCabos)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/TinyMindlessShareware)

**Acrescento**: Por comentário/edição da pergunta soube que queres que o valor esteja entre 3 e 6, então podes:

```
def return_int():
    try: 
        QuantidadeCabos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de cabos: "))
    except ValueError as err: # formato errado
        print('Formato errado')
    else: # caso o try seja bem sucedido, haja o cast para int
        if(3 < QuantidadeCabos < 6): # verificamos se QuantidadeCabos maior que 3 e menor que 6
            return QuantidadeCabos # tudo bem, retornar valor
        print("Digite um valor entre 3 e 6!")
    return return_int() # repetir a pergunta

print("Quantidade de cabos: ", return_int())
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/FarTalkativeUtility)